# How to use "INSERT INTO" command from Access VBA to Sharepoint

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm using a MS Access database linked with a Sharepoint Server. MS Access Forms as FrontEnd and Sharepoint Lists as BackEnd.

Today i can see all the informations from the lists using access forms, without problems.

### What i need:

I'm trying to insert new registers on the list, using a SQL command: "INSERT INTO..."

if there is another possibility to insert the record in the list, may be useful

### What's happening?

When i call the DoCmd.RunSQL(txtsql), i receive a runtime error 3999 saying i'm disconnected from the server.

### My code now:

I tried using recordsets, but didn't succeed.
I need to run this SQL many times, changing the string "txtSql" inside a loop. Like this:

> ```
> Dim MaxSonda As Integer
>
> 'Get the max ID from the list
> MaxSonda = Nz(DMax("IdSonda", "Sondas", "((Sondas.[Tipo Sonda])<>1 Or (Sondas.[Tipo Sonda]) Is Null)"), 0)
> MsgBox "MaxSonda = " & MaxSonda
>
> 'Run the code for each "sonda"
> Do While MaxSonda > 1
>     If Nz(DLookup("[Tipo Sonda]", "Sondas", "Sondas!IdSonda = " & MaxSonda), 1) <> 1 Then
>         DoCmd.OpenTable "Resumo", acViewNormal, acAdd
>         DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataTable, "Resumo", acNewRec
>         
>         txtSql = "INSERT INTO Resumo ( Data, Sonda, Status ) SELECT #" & LastData + 1 & "#, " & MaxSonda & ", 0;"
>         MsgBox txtSql
>         DoCmd.RunSQL txtSql
>         
>         DoCmd.Close acTable, "Resumo", acSaveYes
>     End If
>     MaxSonda = MaxSonda - 1
> Loop
> ```

P.S.: The MsgBox is just for check the steps

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to open the list/table to insert a record. I don't know why you are using loop to insert rows but if that is your intention try this SQL_COMMAND within your loop:

```
If Nz(DLookup("[Tipo Sonda]", "Sondas", "[IdSonda] = " & MaxSonda), 1) <> 1 Then
        txtSql = "INSERT INTO Resumo ( Data, Sonda, Status ) VALUES ('" & LastData + 1 & "'," & MaxSonda & ",0);"
        MsgBox txtSql
        DoCmd.RunSQL txtSql
End If
```

also note #tags are used to insert dates in Access, if you are intend to save dates save them in international format as strings like

```
vba.Format$([date_field],"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

this way you can just save as string without using the #tags.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but didn't solve my problem. The 3999 error still appears.

Comment: can you open your sharepoint list in design mode and make a screen? i would like to know the data types of each column you are trying to insert

Comment: Sorry, but i don't know send images here. //>

Title: Single line of Text //
*Data: Date and Time //
IdSistema: Lookup //
IdOperação: Lookup //
*Sonda: Lookup //
*Status: Lookup //
Resumo:  Multiple lines of text //
Situação: Multiple lines of text //
Próximas: Multiple lines of text //
Adicionais: Multiple lines of text //
PróxPoço: Multiple lines of text //
OK:  Yes/No (Check box) //
OldID:  Number(1, 1.0, 100) //

* = Required

Comment: oldid is required field not sure if your SharePoint workflow inserts auto number or id. I would suggest open the sharepoint list in access and try to add new record manually and see if [data, sondaID, 0] is sufficient to create a new record.

Comment: I've tried to do this, and I could add new records without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help somebody.  I did have the same problem and i solved it removing the sharepoint list from access and add it again. Take a seconds to make a sql query but it works.

greet